# How to redirect to another page using navlink react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react app that is implementing react router. i have my navlinks inside my navbar component inside my home component. Here is my code...

My index.tsx file

```
import App from './App';

 ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Route component={App}/>
  </MemoryRouter>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my App.tsx file;

```
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css'; 
import Home from './screens/Home/Home';
import Business from './screens/Business/BusinessHome';
import Category from './screens/Category';
import ProHome from './screens/Pro/ProHome';
import HireKreator from './screens/HireKreator';
import CategoryHome from './screens/CategoryHome';
import Articles from './screens/Articles';
import Login from './screens/Login';

function App() {

  const location = useLocation();

  return (
     <div className="App">
     <TransitionGroup>
     <CSSTransition classNames="fade" timeout={300} key={location.key}>
     <Router>
        <Switch location={location}>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/pro'>
            <ProHome />
          </Route>
          ....
    </Switch>
    </Router>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

In my home.tsx, i have a navbar component where the navlinks are situated.

```
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then my navbar component

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import logo from "../../images/logo.png";
import './Navbar.css';
import * as HeroIcons from '@heroicons/react/outline';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Transition } from "@tailwindui/react";

export default function Navbar() {

const boxRef = useRef(null);
// const boxOutsideClick = OutsideClick(boxRef); 
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const openNav = () => setOpen(!open);

return (
    <div className="font-sans text-gray-500 font-semibold">
        <div className="flex justify-between lg:justify-between p-6 md:bg-transparent z-0">
            <div className="flex items-center">
                <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="h-10" />
                <ul className="hidden lg:flex">
                    <li className="mx-3 text-red-500 font-bold"><NavLink to="/pro">Kreative Pro</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                </ul>
                <ul className="flex">
                    <li className="mx-3"><NavLink to="/articles">Articles</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
                <button className="bg-red-500 w-32 py-2 rounded-full mx-4 text-white font-semibold">Login</button>
            </nav>
            <HeroIcons.MenuAlt3Icon onClick={openNav} className="h-10 lg:hidden" />
        </div>
        {open ? <div ref={boxRef} className="h-screen absolute inset-0 bg-black opacity-50 z-10"></div> : ''}
        ....
    </div>
);
```

}

I am new to react as i have been using angular for a while. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: were you able to redirect to your ```articles``` route or its giving you any error?

Comment: @Anup i am not able to redirect to any other route. The url changes but the page still stays on the home page

Comment: Try with `Link` instead of NavLink and check if that works for you

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/tradecoder/mongo-office/blob/master/src/components/side-nav.component.js

Comment: Also try this `<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>` and `<Route path='/pro' component={ProHome}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you have to add a `Route` tag in your `index.tsx` file. Route inside route might be causing the issue

Have you tried using `Route` only in the App.tsx file (not in index.tsx)

Just Replace your `index.tsx` file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Route component={App}/>
  </MemoryRouter>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

with

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Alright so changing that gives me a new error. cannot read property location of undefined

Comment: Removing the location variable actually makes it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  using BrowserRouter instead of MemoryRouter in index.tsx. That normally works for me.

Comment: Yes i have. Pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to put the navlink outside the li element like this

```
<NavLink to="/articles"><li className="mx-3">Articles</li></NavLink>
```

Also in app.tsx I think you should put the `<Router>` as the main container and not the div classname app. And render app in index.tsx without

```
<MemoryRouter>
    <Route />
```

Comment: It does not have any effect on it

Comment: I update my answer, try that maybe it will work

Comment: Thanks for your help but still get the same result